# Chosing a suitable Ph.D. program in Mathematics

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics

I am new to this webboard so I am not sure if I can ask this questions here (I am sorry if it is not suitable).

I am currently pursuing a MS degree in Pure Mathematics in a university in America. In a half year time, I will earn the MS degree, and I would like to continue to Ph.D. program. The thing is, for almost two years I spent time at this university, I had a really hard time. I believe that the math program here is quite strong, and I feel that my academic background is not suitable to stay here any longer. So I am trying to find another university to attend Ph.D. program.

To be more precise, I think that I am interested in Number Theory (might be either algebraic or analytic) and Analysis (Real analysis). I also can do relatively good in Algebra. So what I am looking for is a suitable university with relatively decent program in number thoery or analysis (or algebra).

The suitability here I suppose that I mean the program is not too intensive. I do not want to go to the best 50 math graduate school since I know that my academic insight does not that good. I am looking for a university with acceptable Ph.D. math program with relatively easier qualification requirements. I am not sure how to select universities which match my requirement. It is also hard to ask for suggestion for choosing a less intensive Ph.D. program to my advisor. (Most of the time, people are looking for a good best-25-math-grad school. So there is almost no information about a decent or relatively lower math Ph.d. program. That why I decide to ask it here)

If anyone experienced my situation or can suggest what I should do, please leave the advice below.

If you need more specific information in order to give more helpful advice, please mention it.

Comment: I am confused. Number theory is the queen of Mathematics and yet you want to find a relatively lower PhD program to study it. Why?

Comment: I mean I want to find a NEW University to attend Ph.D. program. My point is that I would like to find a new university that appropriate for me. My research interest is Number theory or analysis. I think research interest is one of important factors for choosing university.

Comment: The main reason I need to find a new university is because the deficiency in my academic background. I think that different universities have different expectation for Ph.D. and also different in standard of academic work. I find that my current university has too high expectation that I do not wish to continue studying here. It is too intense and serious.

Comment: I notice that my topic is somehow not appropriate to this stack. Can anyone please recommend where I should post this question or how should I fix my question to fit this acedemia stack ?

Comment: Your question is about seeking recommendations or lists of individual universities. That's why it's put on hold. If you change it to explaining why you look for those universities and asking about how to look for them, you might have chance to get the question re-opened - my opinion.

Comment: I would simply get a list of the Group II and Group III universities in America (such as [here](http://www.ams.org/profession/data/annual-survey/groups_des)), and then visit their web pages, and then make notes on faculty members who appear to do work you're interested in, perhaps writing to some of them personally. For example, I taught for several years at one of the Group III schools listed under "Not Ranked by the 1995 NRC Study", and among the faculty is someone relatively well known in the study of small gaps in primes who could easily supervise research in analytic number theory.

Comment: There is a new proposal in Area 51 that may be a better forum for addressing this question: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97164/graduate-school-admissions-individual-assessment